# not show custom error page when request failed

Tags: nuxt.js

When i catch a error in nuxt/axios plugin, i call the error function provided in context to show error page, but except the 404 error, when the request failed with other status code(ex: 403), the request from node is always `Status Code: 500 NuxtServerError`, and the custom error page not show as expect.

```
  $axios.onError(err => {
    console.log('error:', err); // error: Request failed with status code 403
    // const code = parseInt(err.response && err.response.status)
    // if(code === 403) {
    //   error({ statusCode: 403, message: 'WTF' })
    // }
    error({ statusCode: 403, message: 'WTF' })
  })
```

But it always show NuxtServerError page. How to show my custom error page as expect?

---

**update: even always call error function does not help**

**demo here**: https://codesandbox.io/s/r75v2100lp

add a terminal tab, then execute `npm run dev`

Comment: always call error function then and do check for error code in your error page

Comment: can you create a sandbox

Comment: @AbdullaThanseeh i add a demo, please check it and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should not throw error in `nuxtServerInit` to keep init success. We could handling the error occured in `nuxtServerInit` in try catch and do whatever from catch based on code

```
try {
   const res = await this.$axios.$get("http://httpstat.us/403");
   console.log("res:", res);
   commit("SET_RES", res);
} catch(e){
    console.log("handle error:"+ e)
}
```

here is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/rj23o8ynwq

Comment: thanks a lot, i found that we should not throw any throw in `nuxtServerInit`, otherwise it will cause initError with code 500. If wrap all `nuxtServerInit` code in try-catch, and then handle error in axios `onError` with `error({...})`, it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to get a Nuxt server error you should return something in the onError handler.
for example, you maybe return false or true after handling the error in the onError handler.

create a plugin like axios.js in the plugin folder:

```
export default function ({app, store, $axios, redirect }) 
{

    $axios.onError(
        (error) => {
            console.log(error.response);
            // handle your errors here

            // maybe you maybe reject promise
            return Promise.reject(error.response);

            // Or just return true or false
            // return false
        }
    );
}
```

If you don't want to return anything so you should handle request wherever they've been called:

```
this.$axios.$post(`/api/calendars/events/`, this.event_data).then(
    (data) => {
         // do anything after request
         this.clear_form()
    }
)
```

You don't need to handle errors here just handle them in the axios.js plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```js
export default function ({ $axios, $store }: any) {
  $axios.onError((error: any) => {
    if (
      error.response.code === 401 ||
      error.response.detail === 'Something'
    ) {
      $store.dispatch('auth/modal', error.response.code)
    }
    alert(error.response.data.message)
    return { ...error.response, success: false }
  })
  $axios.onResponse((response: any) => {
    return { ...response, success: true }
  })
}
```

and in the component:

```js
const login = async (): Promise<void> => {
  await $axios
    ?.$post("/api/login", {
      mobile: mobile.value,
    })
    .then((response: any) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: This will be useful when you write a test with VTU for your component, with `try, catch` I've got some problems and errors at the console when I've ran my tests files